# wait for callback causes program to exit

Tags: node.js, callback

Writing simple Node.js CLI text-to-speech app using 'prompt' and 'say'.
How do I make prompt wait for speech to finish before showing new prompt-line?

I moved chat() to outside the callbacks (see commented code at the end), but this causes the prompt to appear early (normal behaviour).

I expected the prompt to return after speech has completed, because chat() is reinitiated once say.speak callback runs.

The program exits right after say.speak finishes, without showing a new prompt.

```
const prompt = require('prompt')
const say = require('say')

chat()

function chat() {
  prompt.get(['chat'], (error, result)=> {
    if(error) return console.log('prompt <ERROR>: '+error.message)
    if (result.chat === 'exit') {
        terminate_self()
    } else if (result.chat == '') {
      say.speak('No input received.', '', '', ()=> {
        chat() // program terminates once speech is complete
      })
    } else {
      // process input here
      say.speak(result.chat, '', '', ()=> {
        chat() // program terminates once speech is complete
      })
    }
    // chat() // program stays alive, BUT prompt returns before speech is completed
  })
}

current result:
user@homeserver:~/Nodejs/ttschat$ node bin.js
chat |  hey
user@homeserver:~/Nodejs/ttschat$

desired result:
user@homeserver:~/Nodejs/ttschat$ node bin.js
chat |  hey
chat |  hey
chat |  exit
user@homeserver:~/Nodejs/ttschat$
```

Comment: i assume that waiting for the speech callback causes the app to believe there are no more processes to run, so it kills itself, am I right in thinking this?

Comment: I've pasted your code in my Linux machine, I've installed Festival package then it runs fine, I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: hmmm, that was the last thing I expected to hear...
just for clarity, you get a new "chat | " line after you have entered some text?
node version?
Im running v12.4.0

Comment: yes, I do, until I enter 'exit'. node version is v11.15.0 on linux-lts 4.19.50.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up, ill purge and reinstall everything related, otherwise using a different system for the time being!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undetermined local issue.

I deleted the project folder, created the same folder, npm installed say and prompt, and pasted the exact same code as before, and it works as expected now.

Many thanks to [dun32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56658514/wait-for-callback-causes-program-to-exit#comment99886780_56658514) for confirming the issue was NOT in the code itself!